# is there a way to connect a button to a function

Tags: javascript

im trying to make it so when i press a button it asks me a question from window.prompt,
i tried this but it didnt work

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            var button = document.getElementById('btn')
            function test(){
                window.prompt("test")
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="btn" onkeyup="myFunction()">test</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass it the name of the function and use the right event. like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function test(){
                window.prompt("test")
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="btn" onclick="test()">test</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have changed the `onkeyup` to `onclick`, because you click the button. and gave it the test function which was the name you choose for the function.